# Gitlabci pipline failes with: syntax error in rules in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, gitlab, sonarcloud

In the below gitlab-ci.yml I am getting a syntax error when I start a pipeline. The rules are the same in other branches and the validation and other pipeline jobs run fine.

**Syntax is incorrect. CI configuration validated, including all configuration added with the includes keyword.
More information
jobs:foo-bar-validation:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax**

```
stages:
  - validation
  - sonar
  - release
  - environments
  - infrastructure-shared
  - build
  - infrastructure-by-environment
  - deploy
  - destroy

variables:
  DOCKER_PYTHON_IMAGE: "${CI_REGISTRY}/foo/bar/python-3.6:2.1.3"
  TERRAFORM_IMAGE: "${CI_REGISTRY}/foo/docker_images/terraform_1.0.1_common_utils:1.1.1"
  SEMANTIC_RELEASE_IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY/foo/docker_images/semantic-release_17.4.4"
  SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
  GIT_DEPTH: 0

include:
  # CI templates
  - local: templates/gitlab/index.yml
  # Sections
  - local: foo/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: bar/.gitlab-ci.yml

release:
  stage: release
  image: $SEMANTIC_RELEASE_IMAGE
  tags:
    - kubernetes
  script:
    - git fetch --all --tags
    - semantic-release
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /(develop|master)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /(develop|master)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never

# ========================================================
# Sonar
# ========================================================
sonar-analysis:
  stage: sonar
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
        - .sonar/cache
  script: 
      - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.organization=foo-sonar -Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml -Dsonar.branch.name=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
  tags:
      - kubernetes
  rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        when: never
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
        changes:
          - microservices/foo/foo/**/*
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
        when: never
  dependencies:
    - foo-bar-validation


environment-variables-files:
  stage: environments
  image: $TERRAFORM_IMAGE
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/prepare
    action: prepare
  tags:
    - kubernetes
  script:
    # TODO: move to terraform base image
    - apk add coreutils
    - bash scripts/generate_envs.sh
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /(master|develop)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /(master|develop)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
  artifacts:
    name: 'env-variables-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'
    expire_in: 5h
    paths:
      - .env
```

Comment: Have you done this? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html#check-cicd-syntax ... at a glance, that `tags` line is missing indentation.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. It must've been messed up when I copied it over. It get's a lint syntax check when the pipeline runs. The output of that is what I put in bold.

Comment: Please follow the steps outlined in the link... the automatic check when the pipeline runs is not particularly beneficial for debugging this - the explicit CI Lint is more helpful... for me, it's flagged the duplicate include of `foo/.gitlab-ci.yml`, but I can't push it much further because I'm missing your dependencies... I'd guess that what it's complaining about (`foo-bar-validation`) is in an include, and not shown in your question.

Comment: I pasted the contents and I got valid syntax.

Comment: I resolved the issue. It wasn't in root gitlab-ci file, it was in one of the dependent files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by comparing one of the dependent files to another branch and resolved the syntax issue.